# In TestNG xml file can i use conditions and how can I parameterize the data in include or exclude tags?

Tags: selenium, include, testng

I am having selenium framework where I am using TestNG as well. I need to execute my test country specific, for that I passed group tag in my testng xml file and excluded the particular country. But Now when I need to exclude other countries so for that i have to go again and again and change the value in the xml file.I want to make it parametrize and want to exclude country name dynamically rather than hard coding of it.
Please refer the below code:-

```
<groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="country name"/>
            </run>
</groups>
```

Comment: Dynamically from where?  Jenkins?

Comment: Yes...dynamically from Jenkins..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a template xml and replace with country name you want using xml's

Your test template should look like  below test-template.xml

```
<groups>
         <run>
            <exclude name="countryname"/>
        </run>
</groups>
```

then you can run your tests with a script something like below

```
for a in `echo country1 country2 country3` 
do
sed -e 's/countryname/$a/g' test-template.xml > testng.xml
//call your test here using testng.xml 
done
```

Comment: `sed -e "s/<exclude name=\"countryname\"/<exclude name=\"${a}\"/" test-template.xml > testng.xml`. Double quote due to $a substitution, g option is not needed for thios sample (1 occurence) and i advice to include the tag header if possible.

Comment: yes single quote does not result in variable substitution so it should be a double quote in sed